# Inside a Keras model, is there a way to mask out some illegal outputs and renormalize the logits?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I am using the Keras functional API. I have some model which outputs a probability distribution by means of a softmax layer:

```
action_logits = Dense(units=self.action_space, activation='softmax')(prev_layer)
```

Next, I mask out illegal actions (or classes, if you will) by multiplying the logits with a bitvector representing the legal actions:

```
mask_illegal_moves = keras.layers.multiply([action_logits, valid_actions])
```

Finally, I want to renormalize the logits, now that I've set the output for some actions to 0. This seems like a very simple thing to do, yet I can't get it to work. For example, another softmax layer did not yield the desired results. Moreover, googling any 'normalization' layer in Keras mostly led me to BatchNorm, which is not what I'm interested in here.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```
action_logits = Dense(units=self.action_space)(prev_layer)
action_logits_masked = Multiply()([action_logits, valid_actions])
action_probs = Activation('softmax')(action_logits_masked)
```

Explained:

- First we get the logits (note that logits are what they are called **before** applying softmax). So don't have `activation='softmax'`
- Apply your mask using `Multiply` layer
- Apply softmax to the masked layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As mentioned in the original post, this does not yield the desired behavior.

For example, these are the masked layer's output:

[0.021, 0.024, 0, 0, 0, ... , 0]

Passing through the softmax activation:
[0.027, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, ..., 0.026]

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: my desired output here would be [0.4666, 0.5334, 0, 0, ... , 0].

Comment: I have found the solution, which was to use a Lambda layer. Thanks a lot for your helpful comment!

Answer (score 0):

I should have clarified my original question. See the helpful response by thushv89. I have found the solution, which was to use a Lambda layer:

```
action_probs = Dense(units=self.action_space, activation='softmax')(skip_2)
action_probs_masked = Multiply()([action_probs, valid_actions])
layer = Lambda(lambda x: x / keras.backend.sum(x, axis=1)[:,None])
actions = layer(action_probs_masked)
```

Comment: One slight clarification - your method is not a proper Softmax - because, for example, Softmax of [0,0,1,0,0] leads to [0.14, 0.14, 0.40, 0.14, 0.14] but your normalization will output [0,0,1,0,0]. Another catch is when the output is [0,1] and mask is [1,0] then your method output [0,0] which is not probability distribution (but it is not a case of Softmax which is outputting probability each time). But it can be suitable for your use-case - just keep that in mind.